# How to pass an Annotation as a parameter?

Tags: java, parameters, annotations, cdi, bean-manager

The CDI class [`BeanManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html) has several methods which take parameters of type `Annotation` or `Annotation...`. For example [`BeanManager.getBeans(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#getBeans%28java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation...%29).

I would like to know how I'm supposed to pass my annotations as parameters to those methods.

I've tried `BeanManager.getBeans(MyBean.class, MyAnnotation.class)`, but it doesn't work that way. I've seen `Class.isAnnotation()`, but there's nothing like `Class.asAnnotation()` to retrieve it as an `Annotation` type.

Neither `BeanManager.getBeans(MyBean.class, @MyAnnotation)` worked, nor did `BeanManager.getBeans(MyBean.class, (Annotation) MyAnnotation.class)`.

How can I retrieve my annotation class as type [`Annotation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. BeanManager.getBeans(...) returns bean instances of the specified type. If you're trying to read the annotations themselves then you need to use reflection as described by @Hirak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an example in the documentation:

```
beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});
```

Source: [16.6. The Bean interface](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_the_literal_bean_literal_interface)

Comment: That did the trick. It's kind of a weird solution, though. I thought the standard Java API would offer something more convienient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> getAnnotation(Class annotationClass)  Returns this element's
>   annotation for the specified type if such an annotation is present,
>   else null.

Or loop through

> getAnnotations()  Returns all annotations present on this element.

To get the annotation.

> object.getClass().getAnnotations()

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Comment: I'm not sure on what I'd call any of those methods. On the annotation class itself?